# boto3 add/update tags to existing AMI

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I am trying to update Tags to AMI with following code.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("ec2")

amis = client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])['Images']

for ami in amis:
    creation_date=ami['CreationDate']
    ami_id = ami['ImageId']
    ami_name = ami['Name']
    try:
        for tag in ami['Tags']:
            if tag['Key'] != 'Servie' and tag['Value'].startswith('lc'):
                print(ami['ImageId'], tag, creation_date)
                ami.create_tags( DryRun=False, Tags=[ { 'Key': 'Service', 'Value': 'it' }, ] )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

But I am getting following error

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'create_tags'
```

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `describe_images` returns a list of dictionaries, like this:

```
[{info for ami1}, {info for ami2}, ..]
```

When looping over that list using `for ami in amis:`, the variable `ami` becomes a dictionary containing all the information for that AMI. You can use `print(ami)` to get a better idea of all the fields that are returned.

Because it is a dictionary, it is not possible to call any EC2 actions on that variable itself.
What you probably want is:

```
client.create_tags(
  Resources=[ami["ImageId"]],
  Tags=[...]
)
```

---

If you were using `boto3.resource` to list all images, you would get a list of `Image`-objects back. It **is** possible to call `create_tags` directly on the `Image`-object.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for ami in ec2.images.filter(Owners=["self"]):
    ami.create_tags(..)
```

See

- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.images
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Image.create_tags